# Force browser cache clearance across all browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, browser, safari

I have the following code on my (all html webpages) :

```
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

However, this is not clearing up caches and my code updates are not showing up. Is there another way to accomplish cache refresh?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use standard HTTP headers to control the caching from the server side, rather than using the `http-equiv` meta tags in your HTML. It allows for controlling proxy caching and other intermediaries, making it a lot more effective. The meta tags also don't help if you have external CSS and JS files. These will still be cached, which may explain why it isn't working correctly for you. You would have to append a randomly generated query string to your resource paths so that the browser appears to be loading a brand new resource every time.

The `http-equiv` values above are actually not in the [HTML 5 specification](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-meta-element.html#attr-meta-http-equiv), so are not valid. You can read more on using HTTP headers correctly in this useful [caching guide](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#META).